# How to get the smooth line for monthly rainfall using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the monthly rainfall data from 1986 to 2016 using ggplot. My dataframe looks like this:

```
head(df)
  Year Month Station Rainfall   Remarks
1 1986   Jan    stn1      0.0  Observed
2 1986   Feb    stn1     10.4  Observed
3 1986   Mar    stn1     16.5  Estimated
4 1986   Apr    stn1     34.0  Observed
5 1986   May    stn1     27.0  Observed
6 1986   Jun    stn1    159.4  Observed

str(df)
'data.frame':   1488 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Year    : chr  "1986" "1986" "1986" "1986" ...
 $ Month   : Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Jan"<"Feb"<"Mar"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Station : Factor w/ 4 levels "stn1","stn2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Rainfall: num  0 10.4 16.5 34 27 ...
 $ Remarks : Factor w/ 2 levels "Estimated","Observed": 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

I tried the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Rainfall, col=Station)) + geom_line()
```

However the above code results in vertical lines plot, while I want to have smooth varying lines.

I want to plot all the four station (stn1 to stn4) such that the color of each line be based on the df$Remarks. 
Also is it possible to have unique color for each station?

Your help would be appreciated

Comment: can you set your year to numeric? df$Year = as.numeric(df$Year)

Comment: Thank you but it do not seem to work.

Comment: Did you want "month-year" to be plotted on the x-axis? For example, Jan-2016, Feb-2016, March-2016, etc?

Comment: I am fine with Year on x axis, but I just want to plot a smooth lines.

Comment: You have (presumably) 12 observations per year. If you're only plotting by year, you'll have 12 y-values (rainfall) for every x-value (year). If you want a single smooth line, you need to figure out some means of aggregating values to have just one value per year—maybe the yearly mean?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach if you create a month-year variable:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

df$Mo_Yr <- as.yearmon(paste0(df$Year, '-', df$Month), "%Y-%b")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Mo_Yr, y=Rainfall, col=Station)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image: plot with month-year on x-axis]

If you want to use different color points for `Remarks` (Observed and Estimated), for a single `Station`, you could try the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Mo_Yr, y=Rainfall)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Remarks)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image: plot with different color points for Remarks]

If you want to plot 2 lines for `Observed` and `Estimated`, you could add `col` argument to `geom_line` as below. Note I added some example data to illustrate. Depending on what data you have available this may (or may not) be what you need.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Mo_Yr, y=Rainfall)) +
  geom_line(aes(col=Remarks)) +
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image: plot with two lines for observed and estimated]

**Data** (for last example)

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Year Month Station Rainfall   Remarks
 1986   Jan    stn1      0.0  Observed
 1986   Feb    stn1     10.4  Observed
 1986   Mar    stn1     16.5  Estimated
 1986   Apr    stn1     34.0  Observed
 1986   May    stn1     27.0  Observed
 1986   Jun    stn1    159.4  Observed
 1986   Jul    stn1     83.1  Estimated
 1986   Aug    stn1     55.7  Observed
 1986   Sep    stn1     12.3  Estimated", header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, is it possible to have different color for df$Remarks if I just plot stn1.

Comment: I tried it that way, but the plot is quite absurd. I don't know why?

Comment: Oh - did you want individual points colored differently if Estimated or Observed? With the same line connecting them? Or did you want 2 lines, one for Observed and one for estimated? With your example, there is only 1 Estimated point, so no line would show up.

Comment: @VaskerSharma - see edited answer. Perhaps this might be more what you are looking for with a single `Station`?

Comment: Thank you. My aim was to have two lines shown but since the Observed and Estimated points are not continuous, I don't think I could reproduce lines for that. Or is there a way?

Comment: I edited the answer again with 2 lines for Observed and Estimated points. Depending on your data, this may or may not be what you need. Let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try passing the stat_smooth parameter

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(y= Rainfall, x= Year, color= Station)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(y= Rainfall, x= Year), method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, 10), se = FALSE)
```

Comment: It still appears as a vertical lines. I tried  df$Year = as.numeric(df$Year). Yet no changes

Comment: Could you try changing the formula parameter. It might be because I tried to use too high of a power function. I am fairly certain that stat_smooth is what you should be using.